# JTable right click mouse ActionListener doesn't return correct row and column values

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouseevent

I have this piece of code that detects a right click on a JTable:

```
jt.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
            JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
            int row = target.getSelectedRow();
            int column = target.getSelectedColumn();
            System.out.println(row + column);
            System.out.println(column);
            System.out.println("right click!");
        }
    }
});
```

I need the row and column values for the system to figure out the contents of the cell being clicked so that I can run functions and stuff, but for my current table jt:
[image]

When I right click on any cell in the row, it returns "right click!" (which is correct) and "-2 -1" for the row and column values. Given that they are in different columns of the table, the row and column values should be positive, and the column values should be different. I'm not understanding what's happening here that made this code not work.

Note: previously I had the `if (e.getClickCount() == 2) { do stuff }` before changing it to the right click function and it worked fine - returned the correct rows and columns.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the table.

Comment: I'm with @AndrewThompson since I cannot reproduce your problem based on what you've posted.

Comment: Of course, there are the `convertColumnIndexToModel(...)` and `convertRowIndexToModel(...)` methods, which are important and possibly needed here, but I don't see these working with `-1` values (a value that suggests that no row or column has been selected yet).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I (was dithering to put off hard things I *should* be doing, and..) made a short code sample to test a theory which was borne out. A right click on a table will not *select **anything.***

Comment: We could vote to re-open, if you'd like to post this

Comment: @AndrewThompson: what say you?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"what say you?"* I say thank you! Answer entered. (Sorry, I got distracted by those other things I should be doing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A right click on a table will not *select* anything.

This is what happens if I right click anywhere in the table as soon as the GUI appears.

[image]

Whereas this is what I see after left clicking in the middle column of the first row, then right click *anywhere* in the table:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class TableSelectionWithMouse {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    String[] headers = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Occupation"};
    String[][] data = {
        {"Yohan", "Jones", "Mouse Wrangler"},
        {"Lucy", "Yang", "Emeritus Professor of Phlogiston"}
    };
    JLabel output = new JLabel("Right click to do .. stuff");

    TableSelectionWithMouse() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        final JTable table = new JTable(data, headers);
        ui.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        ui.add(output, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println(".mouseClicked()" + e);
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                    JTable target = (JTable) e.getSource();
                    int row = target.getSelectedRow();
                    int column = target.getSelectedColumn();
                    output.setText(String.format("Row: %1s Col: %1s", row, column));
                }
            }
        };
        table.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                TableSelectionWithMouse o = new TableSelectionWithMouse();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: This explains what happens, but doesn't explain how to get the row/column on a right click, which is the requirement of the question.